# Чёрный список меток возможен?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, метки, чёрный-список-меток

На metaEnSO попалась метка [blacklist-request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info) с описанием:

> This tag is used in requests for adding one or more tags to the blacklist, preventing them from ever being used again. For other questions about the tag blacklist, use [tag-blacklist].

В первом предложении говорится

> Эта метка используется для запросов на добавление меток в чёрный список, чтобы вопросы с ними больше никогда не задавались.

Получается, что технически чёрный список меток возможен?
Или это какая-то специфичная фича enSO, недоступная на других сайтах сети?

Comment: Фича-то доступна, а вот процедуру добавления интересно было бы узнать...

Comment: Разведаем в ближайшее время.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ближайшее к кому? :)

Comment: @alexolut к рагнарёку, наверное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В какой-то момент чёрный список добавили. Например, для метки [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) при попытке отправить вопрос показывается сообщение:

> Метка [программирование] запрещена.
> Программирование — слишком широкое понятие. Пожалуйста, укажите конкретную технологию, о которой идет речь в вопросе.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: `идет` должно быть через `ё`.

Comment: @alexolut, да, надо бы поменять, давай)

Comment: оно в настройках сайта. В транзифексе этого нет. Так что к Николаю вопрос.