# Возрождение удаленной метки

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки, чёрный-список-меток

Метка [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0) была ранее [удалена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/549/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), однако ее снова создали, и даже утвердили описание.

Как сообщество относится к этому? Нужна ли метка, если нет - то как с ней бороться (и стоит ли)? Ручным удалением с ней бороться явно неэффективно, так как из-за наличия 4 синонимов ее слишком быстро налепляют снова.

Comment: Есть возможность [добавить метки в чёрный список](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2225/213987), [пример с меткой программирование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3303/213987).

Comment: Метка нужная, вы посмотрите сколько человек ее отмечает. Описание добавлено. Что ж тут плохого?

Comment: @VladSpirin то, что она почти не сужает тематику вопроса и потому является неэффективной меткой, добавлять которую бессмысленно. PS: метка [tag:install] туда же.

Comment: Ок, не проблема. Где можно посмотреть список "неугодных меток", чтоб и свое и чужое время зря на них не использовать?

Comment: @VladSpirin эта метка плоха уже хотя бы тем, что ее можно прилепить к каждому второму вопросу. То есть она несет не очень много полезной информации.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это я понял. Но как понять, что надо, а что не надо на ресурсе? А то, как-то все запутано.

Comment: @VladSpirin вот был пост про мета-метки: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/. Признак номер 1 - **"If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag."**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добавили метку в список запрещенных.

Comment: И все её синонимы?

Comment: @VladSpirin Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие были у нее синонимы, я проверю.

Comment: error, bug эти точно помню

Comment: @VladSpirin Проверил. Когда, к примеру, добавляем метку «bug», появляется надпись «Метка [ошибка] запрещена».

Comment: Есть ещё разрешённая "ошибки".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Сегодня два вопроса нашел с меткой "ошибки"